# How to force SSL encryption?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We use the following code to communicate with `DynamoDB`:

```
using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    var table = Table.LoadTable(client, "Users");
    var item = await table.GetItemAsync(id);
}
```

How can I force `AWS.SDK for .NET` to always use SSL connections? This is very important as we want to store user data including passwords in `DynamoDB`.

Comment: DynamoDB uses SST/TLS by default.

Comment: @JaredHatfield Thank you for quick reply, but is there any official information from Amazon to prove this statement?

Comment: If you want to explicitly set the protocol to HTTPS you can do that when you construct the AmazonDynamoDBClient by providing a AmazonDynamoDBConfig with the Protocol set to HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet that will allow you to set the endpoint explicitly:

```
AmazonDynamoDBConfig config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
config.ServiceURL = "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(config);
```

Feel free to replace the region (us-east-1) with any other AWS region.

This example is based on the documentation available here on setting the endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TestingDotNetApiSamples.html

Comment: updated my answer with an explanation. thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, I will not delete my first comment (it is no longer relevant). This comment will also be deleted in a few minutes. Happy SO adventuring!